# Cropping layer in my keras model has zero dimensions

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network

I create simple model with keras to understand the cropping layer

```
def other_model():
    x = keras.Input(shape = (64,64,3))
    conv = keras.layers.Conv2D(5, 2)(x)
    crop = keras.layers.Cropping2D(cropping = 32)(conv)
    model = keras.Model(x,crop)
    model.summary()

    return model
```

But I get the following summary

---

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

input_12 (InputLayer)        (None, 64, 64, 3)         0

---

conv2d_21 (Conv2D)           (None, 63, 63, 5)         65

---

## cropping2d_13 (Cropping2D)   (None, 0, 0, 5)           0

Total params: 65
Trainable params: 65
Non-trainable params: 0

---

Why are the 1st and the 2nd dimensions of Cropping2D equal to zero? 
They are supposed to be 32

Comment: Ok. One way to implement it is to use 2 tuples in the cropping layer defenition:       crop = keras.layers.Cropping2D(cropping = ((15,32),(15,32)))(conv). But I want to use only one integer number for this

Comment: But I still can't get 32x32 size, I can get only smaller one

Comment: If you chose cropping = (a,b) then your image will be cut off by the value a on right and left sides and  by value b on top and bottom. 2a and 2b in conclusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just choose the number of pixels which will be cut off at every side of your image. I would chose it bigger or equal than the half size of the image, so it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear in the documentation, but if you give a single integer value (cropping=32) as parameter, it crops off 32 pixels on *each* side of the image.

If you have an image with 64x64 pixels and cropping=32, the target size therefore will be 0x0 pixels...

If you want to have a target size of 32x32 pixels, you have to give `cropping=16`